# Is it ok to install a SSAS 2016 instance next to a SQL Server 2014 instance?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-2014, ssas-tabular, ssas-2016

Should I expect any problems installing a SQL Server Analysis Services 2016 tabular instance next to a SQL Server 2014 database engine? (e.g. due to an update of some shared components)

I'm mostly worried about any issues related to the running database engine, since this is a production server.

Thanks.

Comment: Try it in Dev first. You may want to ask this on dba.stackexchange.com as well. Also, why would you want to burden your production SQL Server with an Analysis Server? Put them on separate servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported by Microsoft.

[side-by-side install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/work-with-multiple-versions-and-instances-of-sql-server#using-includessnoversionincludesssnoversion-mdmd-side-by-side-with-previous-versions-of-includessnoversionincludesssnoversion-mdmd)